# How to take CPU memory(UCHAR Buffer) in to GPU memory(ID3D11Texture2D Resource)

Tags: gpu, directx-11, direct3d

The code here will run in GPU and capture windows screen, it give us `ID3D11Texture2D` Resource. Using `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map` I taking GPU `resource` in to `BYTE` buffer from `BYTE`buffer in to CPU Memory `g_iMageBuffer` its a `UCHAR`.

Now I want to do reverse engineering, I want to take `g_iMageBuffer`buffer(CPU Memory) in to `ID3D11Texture2D`(GPU memory). Please someone help me how to do this reverse engineering I am new to graphical part.

```
//Variable Declaration
IDXGIOutputDuplication* IDeskDupl;
IDXGIResource*          lDesktopResource = nullptr;
DXGI_OUTDUPL_FRAME_INFO IFrameInfo;
ID3D11Texture2D*        IAcquiredDesktopImage;
ID3D11Texture2D*        lDestImage;
ID3D11DeviceContext*    lImmediateContext;
UCHAR*                  g_iMageBuffer=nullptr;

//Screen capture start here
hr = lDeskDupl->AcquireNextFrame(20, &lFrameInfo, &lDesktopResource);

// >QueryInterface for ID3D11Texture2D
hr = lDesktopResource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&lAcquiredDesktopImage));
lDesktopResource.Release();

// Copy image into GDI drawing texture
lImmediateContext->CopyResource(lDestImage,lAcquiredDesktopImage);
lAcquiredDesktopImage.Release();
lDeskDupl->ReleaseFrame();  

// Copy GPU Resource to CPU
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc;
lDestImage->GetDesc(&desc);
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource;
UINT subresource = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, 0, 0);
lImmediateContext->Map(lDestImage, subresource, D3D11_MAP_READ_WRITE, 0, &resource);

std::unique_ptr<BYTE> pBuf(new BYTE[resource.RowPitch*desc.Height]);
UINT lBmpRowPitch = lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Width * 4;
BYTE* sptr = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(resource.pData);
BYTE* dptr = pBuf.get() + resource.RowPitch*desc.Height - lBmpRowPitch;
UINT lRowPitch = std::min<UINT>(lBmpRowPitch, resource.RowPitch);

for (size_t h = 0; h < lOutputDuplDesc.ModeDesc.Height; ++h)
{
    memcpy_s(dptr, lBmpRowPitch, sptr, lRowPitch);
    sptr += resource.RowPitch;
    dptr -= lBmpRowPitch;
}

lImmediateContext->Unmap(lDestImage, subresource);
long g_captureSize=lRowPitch*desc.Height;
g_iMageBuffer= new UCHAR[g_captureSize];
g_iMageBuffer = (UCHAR*)malloc(g_captureSize);

//Copying to UCHAR buffer 
memcpy(g_iMageBuffer,pBuf,g_captureSize);
```

Comment: A better solution than the ``malloc`` and ``memcpy`` at the end would be to just "move" the buffer allocated in your ``std::unique_ptr<>`` which you can get by calling ``release``. Of course, that assumes you clean up with delete instead of free--or better yet just use a ``std::unique_ptr<>``. If you must use ``free``, then use ``malloc`` which initializing the ``std::unique_ptr<>`` in the first place (and provide a custom deleter that uses ``free`` instead of ``delete``).. Also note that your ``new`` followed by a ``malloc`` is leaking memory.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn ya i got it ... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reverse engineering. What you describe is called "loading a texture".

[How to: Initialize a Texture Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476905.aspx)
[How to: Initialize a Texture From a File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476904.aspx)

> As you appear to be new to DirectX programming, consider working through the [DirectX Tool Kit for DX11 tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). In particular, make sure you read the section on [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) and [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).